# prevent load image on nodejs request

Tags: node.js, parsing, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I am using [request](https://github.com/request/request) and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to pars some web pages in nodejs. We do this every day more than 20 times so we lost many bandwidth for loading images and css content that is not useful for parsing.

I used some code like this:

```
request(url, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('.n-item').each(function(i, element){
      //do something
    });
  }
});
```

**1-** I want to know this is correct that **request** loads images/content and may lost my server bandwidth ?

**2-** Show me a solution to prevent load images/content

thanks

Comment: one out-of-the-box approach would be to put something like nginx between your node app and the webserver(s) you're hitting.  Then have nginx just return a tiny image for any image requests.

Comment: Yes, request only loads the url and not related assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request itself doesn't parse HTML code or run Javascript. It will only download the source or the URL that you enter. If it's a normal website, it literally returns the HTML source.

The only time you can pull images with "request" is if you use a URL that directly links to an image. E.g `http://example.com/image.jpg`